# While without global

Tags: scope, global-variables, julia, scoping

This snippet of code is from [JuliaBoxTutorials](https://github.com/JuliaComputing/JuliaBoxTutorials/blob/master/intro-to-julia/04.%20Loops.ipynb)

```
myfriends = ["Ted", "Robyn", "Barney", "Lily", "Marshall"]
i = 1;

while i <= length(myfriends)
    friend = myfriends[i]
    println("Hi $friend, it's great to see you!")
    i += 1
end
```

giving this error when run with Julia v1.0

```
UndefVarError: i not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at ./In[12]:5 [inlined]
 [2] top-level scope at ./none:0
```

But when `i += 1` is replaced with `global i += 1` it works. I guess this was still working in v0.6 and the tutorial will be adapted once the new Intro to Julia is published this Friday.

I was just wondering, is it possible, to make a while loop without stating a global variable?

Comment: I guess the for loop is more suitable for this example.

Comment: Have you tried i = i + 1?

Comment: Yes, it also gives me the same error:
    UndefVarError: i not defined
    
    Stacktrace:
     [1] top-level scope at ./In[12]:5 [inlined]
     [2] top-level scope at ./none:0

Comment: I just saw in http://bogumilkaminski.pl/files/julia_express.pdf it is mentioned that 
"global would not be needed if the loop were inside a function"

Comment: The scoping rules have changed from v0.7+ on. See my reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930537/scope-of-variables-in-julia/51930866#51930866

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Michael Paul and @crstnbr already replied in the comments, the scoping rules have been changed ([Scope of variables in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930537/scope-of-variables-in-julia/51930866#51930866)). The `for` and `while` loop introduce a new scope and have no access to the outside (global) variables. You can get scope access using the `global` keyword but the recommended workflow is wrapping your code in functions.

One of the benefits of the new design is that the user is forced to avoid such global constructs which directly affect the performance of functions - which cannot be type stable when they access global variables.

One downside is the confusion when experimenting in the REPL and seeing such errors.

In my opinion the new behaviour is the cleaner one with respect to predictability. It was however a very tough and long-running discussion within the whole Julia community ;)

There is currently a discussion if the REPL will be changed to behave like the old one by making use of `let`-wraps: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28789
This is something which is not practical to be done manually (much more complicated then using the `global` keyword), see the example by Stefan Karpinski: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28789#issuecomment-414666648

Anyways, for the sake of completeness (**although I would not recommend doing this**) here is a version using `global`:

```
myfriends = ["Ted", "Robyn", "Barney", "Lily", "Marshall"]
i = 1;
N = length(myfriends)    

while i <= N  # you cannot even call a function here
              # with a global, like length(myfriends)
    global i, myfriends
    friend = myfriends[i]
    println("Hi $friend, it's great to see you!")
    i += 1
end
```

Note however that this is also completely valid:

```
myfriends = ["Ted", "Robyn", "Barney", "Lily", "Marshall"]

greet(friend) = println("Hi $friend, it's great to see you!")

for friend in myfriends
    greet(friend)
end
```

Comment: Can you add an example without global, making use of a let wrapper? That would make the answer even more complete.

Comment: I added a comment on the `let`-wrapping. I don't think an example would be helpful, as it will probably cause more confusion, see my explanation ;)

Comment: Are you sure about not being able to call a function in the while condition? It runs without problems when I try, see also my answer. The issue comments on the let scoping was very interesting to read, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Loops do have read access to global variables, so you can print or use them to define other variables. Also, writing to `i` within the loop will not cause an error because a new separate `i` variable will be created. Julia will only complain if you try to read and write `i` within the same loop, such as `i=i+1`. This is because Julia doesn't know whether you want the global or local `i` without declaring it as such. For this reason, `println(i)` and `i=2` may be stated individually without error in a loop but not together. These subtleties were confusing me when I was testing scope for myself.

Comment: @NathanBoyer in fact the scoping rules has been changed and there are some rules which were introduced to make this more transparent. It's indeed confusing ;)

Answer (score 3):

I found that this works in Julia v1.0:

```
let 
    myfriends = ["Ted", "Robyn", "Barney", "Lily", "Marshall"]
    i = 1;

    while i <= length(myfriends) # this function here seems to work no problem
        friend = myfriends[i]
        println("Hi $friend, it's great to see you!")
        i = i + 1 # gives syntax error when prefixed with global 
    end
end
```

In fact, it will give me a syntax error if I try to make i global :) within the while loop.