# Scope of for loops in julia

Tags: julia

From the [Quantitative Economics course](https://lectures.quantecon.org/jl/julia_by_example.html), I came across the following example:

```
ϵ = randn(1:100)
ϵ_sum = 0.0
m = 5
for ϵ_val in ϵ[1:m]
    ϵ_sum = ϵ_sum + ϵ_val
end
ϵ_mean = ϵ_sum / m
```

The code spits out an error `ERROR: UndefVarError: ϵ_sum not defined`, even though ϵ_sum was defined in first line of the code. After some painful browsing of the internet, the hypothesis was that the [for loop has weird local completely isolated scope](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28789). This seems to be the case, as similar code that I have been trying to port from matlab has weird issues in julia, particularly code growing arrays and variables in for loops.

But the hypothesis of the local scope in for loops is discarded, because the following code runs without an issue:

```
e = 1
for num in 1:100
    println(e)
end
```

What is the difference of the scope between the two pieces of code?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037753/while-without-global for an explanation what happens here.