# Julia 1.1 x=x+1 in for loop returned error

Tags: julia

I'm using Julia 1.1 and I tried to use for loop do the following simple things:

```
i_index=1;
for index in (1:100)
    i_index=i_index+1;
end
```

However, I got an error saying:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: i_index not defined
```

I have tried several times and variations, but they all failed to work. Is this a bug? or why Julia can't do this simple iterative addition?

Comment: Looking at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396269/julia-1-0-undefvarerror-scope-of-variable/52396319 I assume you need to add `global`, like this: `global i_index=i_index+1;`

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Thank you. But could you explain a bit? (I didn't even define a function, but only used a for loop...) Where does that "global" come from?

Comment: Because you didn't define a function, you are working in a global scope and because of that, you defined `i_index` in a global scope so you need to access it using `global`. In a function your code would work as is

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Please correct me if there's a mistake... 1. I defined a variable in global, then I ran a for loop, and julia see for loop as an independent environment(like a function), so I needed to call global variable in a global for loop?

Comment: Correct, but instead of *environment* you should call it *scope* which is a block of code where the variables can bee seen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While without global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037753/while-without-global)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the REPL:

```
i_index=1;
for index in (1:100)
    global i_index;
    i_index=i_index+1;
end
```

This is because of variable scope, see in [Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/index.html). Note that the examples there pertain to the REPL.

Comment: Really? You just stole my suggestion from the comment and didn't even try to explain to the OP *why* your code works and OP's don't. Very low quality answer

Comment: I didn't, I went into Julia documentation and found this: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/index.html. I'll change my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Please at least explain to the OP what is the actual issue here so future readers could benefit from this as well