# Does scoping in julia 1.0.0 with for-loops make sense to beginners?

Tags: scope, global-variables, julia

In julia 1.0.0, I get the following for-loop scoping behavior:

```julia
julia> counts = 0
0
julia> for i in 1:10
       counts += 1
   end
ERROR: UndefVarError: counts not defined
```

I found the solution was to make the `counts` variable `global` inside the `for` loop.

```julia
julia> for i in 1:10
           global counts += 1
       end
julia> counts
10
```

However, as a newcomer to julia this behavior almost made me quit the language because it seems so different from other languages.

Now that I see the solution above, I wonder if this is intuitive to beginning julia users.  It was not intuitive to me, though I was finally able to solve it after quite a bit of time.

Here is the confusing part.  I thought making a variable global when it was initialized would solve the problem.  It does not:

```julia
julia> global c = 0
julia> for i in 1:10
           c += 1
       end
ERROR: UndefVarError: c not defined
```

It would seem natural that the global scope of `c` above would flow down into the for-loop, but the first initialization of `c` in the for-loop apparently creates a different for-loop local `c`.

Does this make sense to experienced julia developers?

Comment: This, question is very close to [_"a rant in disguise"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).  Wouldn't it be better for other SO users to just ask a question about Julia's variable scoping?

Comment: @rickhg12hs  I did not intend it as a rant at all.  I started coding in Julia on Sept. 4, 2018, this problem almost caused me to skip the language entirely.  I asked this question the next day on Sept. 5, 2018.  I hope it is a help to others.

Comment: There are previous SO questions about Julia's variable scoping.  E.g., see the links in @crstnbr's answer.  And though I "feel" for you, and it's perfectly fine to discuss feelings, I don't think *SO* is the place for feelings about programming.  Much of what you write here is subjective - "beginners", "makes sense", "intuitive", etc. How does that apply to the question?  What does your question add to SO that isn't already here? ... or in the Julia documentation?  Ask yourself, after you have written your question, and it is answered, has SO been improved?  Will other SO users benefit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think there is agreement that, for interactive usage, this behavior is not optimal and it is likely going to change to the expected behavior in the REPL, IJulia etcetera soon. You can find the discussion here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28789

Note, however, that everything works as expected once you wrap it into a local scope, such as a function or a `let` block for example.

See my answer here: [Scope of variables in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930537/scope-of-variables-in-julia/51930866#51930866) for some more information/references.