# Julia 1.0 UndefVarError - Scope of Variable

Tags: for-loop, scope, julia, scoping

I am moving from Julia 0.7 to 1.0. It seems that Julia's rule for the scope of variables changed from 0.7 to 1.0. For example, I want to run a simple loop like this:

```julia
num = 0
for i = 1:5
    if i == 3
        num = num + 1
    end
end
print(num)
```

In Julia 0.7 (and in most of other languages), we could expect `num = 1` after the loop. However, it will incur `UndefVarError: num not defined` in Julia 1.0. I know that by using `let` I can do this

```julia
let
num = 0
for i = 1:5
    if i == 3
        num = num + 1
    end
end
print(num)
end
```

It will print out 1. But I do want to get the `num = 1` outside the loop and the `let` block. Some answers suggest putting all code in a `let` block, but it will incur other problems including `UndefVarError` while testing line-by-line. Is there any way instead of using `let` blocking? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52187073/10316987).

Add `global` as shown below inside the loop for the `num` variable.

```
num = 0
for i = 1:5
    if i == 3
        global num = num + 1
    end
end
print(num)
```

Running in the Julia 1.0.0 REPL:

```
julia> num = 0
0
julia> for i = 1:5
           if i == 3
               global num = num + 1
           end
       end
julia> print(num)
1
```

**Edit**

For anyone coming here new to Julia, the excellent comment made in the answer below by vasja, should be noted:

> Just remember that inside a function you won't use global, since the scope rules inside a function are as you would expect:

See that answer for a good example of using a function for the same code without the scoping problem.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I had put the global before the num outside the loop and it did not work.

Comment: "It seems that Julia's rule for the scope of variables changed from 0.7 to 1.0" that phrase is the UNDERSTATEMENT OF THE YEAR!!!

Comment: @StevenSiew   Yes, you hit the nail on the head!

Comment: If the [question is fully answered by another SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), shouldn't the OP be directed there in a comment to his question?

Comment: Good comment.  I debated that one myself.  However, if someone is new to a language, sometimes an exact answer to specific code can be easier to understand than a more general answer.  Your link has [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) for example.  This is the first month I have been really doing anything on stackoverflow (apart from a little with the R language some years ago).  Thanks.  PS: (I did provide a link, but did not mention duplicate.)

Answer (score 1):

Just remember that inside a function you won't use `global`, since the scope rules inside a function are as you would expect:

```
function testscope()
    num = 0
    for i = 1:5
        if i == 3
            num = num + 1
        end
    end
    return num
end


julia> t = testscope()
1
```

The unexpected behaviour is only in REPL.
More on this [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/repl-and-for-loops-scope-behavior-change/13514)

Comment: Oh Thanks! This is helpful because I am indeed writing functions. Then it is bothering since before I finish the whole function, I have to guarantee those intermediate steps work by testing them line-by-line, in which case I need to use `global`, but then it will incur syntax error if I don't delete those `global`s when I am ready to call the function.