# I cannot run a .jl file in the console using julia 1.0.2 but I can using julia 0.6

Tags: scope, julia

The script is really simple, and it is stored in a file named 001.jl

```
sum = 0

for i in 1:10-1
    if i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0
        sum = sum + i
    end
end

println("The sum is ", sum)
```

Nevertheless when I try to run it in the console I get this error

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: sum not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /Users/aceves/Documents/MyScripts/julia/001.jl:5 [inlined]
 [2] top-level scope at ./none:0
 [3] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [6] include(::String) at ./client.jl:392
 [7] top-level scope at none:0
in expression starting at /Users/aceves/Documents/MyScripts/julia/001.jl:3
```

Runs perfectly with julia 0.6 though. It also works if I type exactly that in the REPL of the 1.0.2 version. I'm obviously missing one detail. does anyone has an idea which?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia 1.0 UndefVarError - Scope of Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396269/julia-1-0-undefvarerror-scope-of-variable)

Comment: The reason is that scoping rules changed in Julia 1.0.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem got solved by changing the line inside the loop to `global sum = sum + i`. It is a weird change though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it was said in the comments the problem is in scoping  change in Julia 1.0. 
It should be noted that in many examples such as this the simplest and fastest solution is surrounding all your code within a single `let` block. The `let` block introduces a local scope:

```
let    
    sum = 0        
    for i in 1:10-1
        if i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0
            sum = sum + i
        end
    end        
    println("The sum is ", sum)    
end
```

Comment: Thanks :D This will help while I read the new documentation. Sorry I cannot upvote the answer, I'm still not worthy